# bootstrap carousel image not sliding with parallax

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, parallax, parallax.js

I am developing a site with parallax effect using the following plugin :-https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/

I need to implement a slider in the first section. But the problem is that parallax plugin use

```
data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg"
```

to render images.

Even though the slides are sliding, the image remains the same..i.e the image of the first slide.

I need to slide the images as well. Is there a workaround for this :-

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://localhost:8000/bs/project/images/home-slide-banner1.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            Caption 1
        </div>
   </div>
<div class="item parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://localhost:8000/bs/project/images/home-interactive-bg.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://localhost:8000/bs/project/images/goodwp.com_18663.jpg">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: IS this across all browser or a certain one?

Comment: Sorry to bring this up, but have you got any solution to this? I am stuck at the same point.

Comment: Is there any solution or workaround related to this issue?